# A new input system prevents you from pressing buttons on the canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I couldn't press the button in the UI that pops up when I press the E key.I think I've cleared all the typical mistakes.

- GraphicRaycaster" is attached to Canvas.
- Check "Interactable" and "BlocksRaycasts" in CanvasGroup.
- Check "RaycastTarget".
- Make sure there is no other UI overlapping in front of the target UI.
- No "invisible UI" overlapping in front of the target UI

Then I realized that the "Starter Assets - Third Person Character Controller - PlayerArmature" on the hierarchy might be the problem.
I was able to manipulate the UI by trying to delete it.
When I looked into it, I found out that a new input system was being used.
I interpreted it as needing to be changed to an action map to manipulate the UI by looking at the official documentation and other articles.
So I added a script to change the action map to that of the UI when the UI is displayed.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Keyboard.current.eKey.wasPressedThisFrame)
        {
            if (optionView.gameObject.activeSelf == false)
            {
                _playerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap("UI");

            }else if (optionView.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
            {
                _playerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap("Player");

            }
        }
```

I couldn't do this either.

I changed the action map from the default one to the UI one and it didn't work.
The repository is here.
https://github.com/eiei114/WwiseTestProject

Comment: As per the site's tagging guidelines, please do not put tags in your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Input system has this problem of working in Game and on the Canvas at the same time. I faced the problem too. I found that disabling the main character which used the Player Input Controller was clashing with the Canvas controller, which helped. Or even better use both the old and the new systems together.